# SwiftMailer email in Kohana triggers array to string conversion

Tags: php, email, kohana-3, swiftmailer

I'm trying to email in Kohana using SwiftMailer but keep coming across an error about an array to string conversion.

My code is thus:

```
$mailer = Email::connect();
$to = 'boboz@gmail.com';
$from = 'no-reply@yahoo.com';
$subject = 'Hey, say hello!';
$body = 'Hello World!';
$message_swift = Swift_Message::newInstance($subject, $body)
    ->setFrom($from)
    ->setTo($to);
if ($mailer->send($message_swift))
{
    echo 'Massage Send! Bravo!';
}
else
{
    echo 'Message failed! Booo!';
}
```

The error displayed:

> MODPATH/kohana-email/vendor/swift/classes/Swift/Transport/MailTransport.php [ 183 ]
>   Error: ErrorException [ Notice ]: Array to string conversion

The part of SwiftMailer it's referring to is here:

```
178       $headers = str_replace("\r\n.", "\r\n..", $headers);
179       $body = str_replace("\r\n.", "\r\n..", $body);
180     }
181     
182     if ($this->_invoker->mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers,
183       sprintf($this->_extraParams, $reversePath)))
184     {
185       if ($evt)
186       {
187         $evt->setResult(Swift_Events_SendEvent::RESULT_SUCCESS);
188         $evt->setFailedRecipients($failedRecipients);
```

Why am I getting this variable conversion error?

Comment: Ran your code and could not replicate

Comment: What could be causing it, if it works on your machine?

Comment: I think I am running Kohana 3.2. I use git pull to update it and it says everything is up to date.

Comment: So what else could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure the driver is set to the right value in the config file called email.php found in the config folder.

Comment: `'driver' => 'native',` and  `'options' => NULL` is valid for default config, I was using `'options' => array()`

Answer (score 0):

`$to` should be an array:

```
$to = array($email => $name);
```

or just

```
$to = array($email);
```

you could do:

```
$message_swift = Swift_Message::newInstance($subject, $body)
->setFrom(array($from))
->setTo(array($to));
```

Same thing goes with `setFrom`.

Comment: it says there is a problem on line 183: sprintf($this->_extraParams, $reversePath)))

Comment: Are you spamming TorrentLeech?

Comment: separate all the calls to message_swift ($message_swift = Swift_Message::newInstance($subject, $body); $message_swift->setFrom(array($from)); $message_swift->setTo(array($to)); see after which line you get the error

Comment: but after which line? i mean, which one of your lines of code starts the sequence that ends up with this error?

Comment: Found it! It was a error in the configuration. 'driver' => 'smtp',